# PC-SAFT giving random results or the same error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to calculate the bubble point pressure of methanol in a methanol-isobutane mixture at 110 degC using PC-SAFT parameters. The code is either giving out the same error or a different value for pressure randomly. Have I set the k_ij parameters incorrectly or does the issue lie in something else?

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from pcsaft import flashTQ # documentation: https://pcsaft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

'''
Data for methanol: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ie010954d
Data for isobutane: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ie0003887
'''
t = 110 + 273.15 # K
q = 0.2 # fraction, that is evaporated
x0 = 0.75 # mole fraction of methanol in mixture
x = np.asarray([x0, 1-x0])
pcsaft_params = {'m': np.asarray([1.5255, 2.2616]), # [methanol, isobutane]
                 's': np.asarray([3.2300, 3.7574]),
                 'e': np.asarray([188.90, 216.53]),
                 'e_assoc': np.asarray([0.035176]),
                 'vol_a': np.asarray([2899.5])}
pcsaft_params['k_ij'] = np.asarray([[0, 0],
                                    [0, 0]])

pvap, xl, xv = flashTQ(t, q, x, pcsaft_params)
print('Bubble point pressure: {} Pa'.format(pvap))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You need to add zeros for isobutane to the arrays of e_assoc and vol_a parameters
2. The `vol_a` and `e_assoc` parameters have been flipped and matched with the incorrect keys

Here is how the parameters dict should look:

```
pcsaft_params = {'m': np.asarray([1.5255, 2.2616]), # [methanol, isobutane]
                 's': np.asarray([3.2300, 3.7574]),
                 'e': np.asarray([188.90, 216.53]),
                 'vol_a': np.asarray([0.035176, 0]),
                 'e_assoc': np.asarray([2899.5, 0])}
```

And let me explain why those extra zeros are needed for isobutane. If one of those additional parameters is being used, then a value needs to be given for every component in the system. Otherwise the pcsaft module doesn't know which component the association parameters should be assigned to. For compounds without the additional term, just use zeros.

Comment: I've tried this fix before and with the added zeros. The result in this case will _only_ be an error, no occasional random value of pressure. Is there a chance you could check the k_ij parameters? I've set them to 0 due to my uncertainty of their actual value.

Comment: Yes, there is a second error as well. I updated my answer to point out both issues.